# Dynamic mapping of DataTable ColumnNames to SQL Database Column Headers over multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, csv, mapping

I need to merge data of a .csv file with the data of multiple SQL database tables.

What I get is a .csv file with approximately 2000 lines of rows. Those rows contain data of two tables, once for a customer table and once for contract infos to this customer (1:n relation).

The data would then be compared, new data will be imported, existing one updated, this counts for both tables, the customers and the contracts.

On the other hand, I need a dynamic, rather simple mapping: csv header "X" = table column "Y". The important bit here is, that it has to be dynamic, which essentially means, I'd be able to, at any point in time, add more columns to my .csv file, create an entry in my mapping file and it would still fetch this new entry. Vice-versa of course, if I change a mapped column or remove one the same behavior.

What I have done:
I parse the .csv file with GenericParser to a datatable with column headers. I created an ini file which is essentially just mapping the headers headers from that datatable to the table on my SQL server. I then replace the datatable columnNames with the column header names from my SQL table, which I, again, fetch from my mapping.

My Problem:
What would be the best way to make sure, my mapping knows which SQL table that column is part of and how would that translate into my SQL statements for the merging process.

I could also imagine, that this is completely the wrong way to do this. If so, I am open for suggestions.

Main:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Init Config
        _mainConfig = new Configuration.Main(@"C:\temp\kosy\mainconfig.cfg");
        
        // get Import Files
        String csvFileKunden = _mainConfig.csvFileKunden;
        String csvFileVerträge = _mainConfig.csvFileVerträge;
        
        // Parse to Datatables
        var dataTableKunden = getDataTableKosy(csvFileKunden);
        var dataTableVerträge = getDataTableKosy(csvFileVerträge);

        // Init Mapping
        var mappingConfig = new Config(_mainConfig.mappingFile);
        var sk = "mappingKunden";
        var sv = "mappingVerträge";

        // Replace ColumNames with Mapped Names
        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTableKunden.Columns) {
            dataTableKunden.Columns[column.ColumnName].ColumnName = mappingConfig.Read(column.ColumnName, sk);
        }
        foreach (DataColumn column1 in dataTableVerträge.Columns)
        {
            dataTableVerträge.Columns[column1.ColumnName].ColumnName = mappingConfig.Read(column1.ColumnName, sv);
        }
        // Replace TableNames with Mapped Names
        dataTableKunden.TableName = mappingConfig.Read("Kunden", "tablemapping");
        dataTableVerträge.TableName = mappingConfig.Read("Verträge", "tablemapping");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Datatable Parsing:

```
     private static DataTable getDataTableKosy(string csvFile) {
        DataTable retVal;
        using (var parser = new GenericParserAdapter(csvFile)) {
            parser.ColumnDelimiter = ';';
            parser.FirstRowHasHeader = true;
            retVal = parser.GetDataTable();
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Testdata that I work with:
[Link to file sharing (Dracoon)](https://dracoon.team/public/download-shares/uG3on1CwwDGMux37bWA2gSFkB9ADullr)

Comment: First; i would use the DataTable just like you do and then i would change the Column names and table name dynamically according to mapping.
Second: share your sample data and mapping data so we can post some sample code

Comment: You can use GetSchema to get the tables and columns in the tables.

Comment: @ArgeKumandan As you suggested, I edited the post and added the code & testdata. Thanks for your help in advance!